# Crear array multidimensional en JS con push

Tags: javascript, array, push

Desde este foreach obtengo diferentes lineas (he comentado como lo he intentado, pero nada):

```
respuesta2.forEach( function(valor2){                              
  //resultados_f2[valor2.ronda].push([parseInt(valor2.victorias_1), parseInt(valor2.victorias_2)]);
  console.log("-"+valor2.ronda+"-> "+parseInt(valor2.victorias_1)+" "+parseInt(valor2.victorias_2));
                              
});
```

El resultado del console anterior es el siguiente:

```
-2-> 1 0
-1-> 1 2
-1-> 2 1
```

El array que quiero conseguir es el siguiente:

```
var resultados_f2 = [ 
    [[2,1], [1,2]],
    [[1,2]] 
];
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Quiero que todos las lineas que tengan el mismo `valor2.ronda` estén en un array dentro del array `resultados_f2`.

Comment: Te falta código relevante, como cuando defines los atributos (`.ronda` y `.victorias`). Además no das un contexto muy claro, pero para ver si entiendo, **quieres añadir un array con dos elementos dentro e otro array?

Comment: Tampoco lo veo muy claro. ¿El segundo elemento de `resultados_f2` no debería ser `[[1,0]]`? ¿En qué momento estás declarando `resultados_f2[valor2.ronda]` como un objeto con el método `push`? ¿Existe la ronda cero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con el método [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).
`reduce` iterará sobre el *array* generando un nuevo valor basado en el elemento actual de la iteración y un valor acumulado.

En tu caso, el valor acumulado es una *array* (aquello que quieres de resultado).

```
const digest = arr =>
    // acc es el valor acumulado
    // cur es el objeto actual
    arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        // Sacamos la ronda del current
        const { ronda } = cur;
        // Generamos el elemento a insertar
        const val = [cur.victorias_1, cur.victorias_2];

        // Comprobamos que exista
        // para añadir o crear.
        acc[ronda] = acc[ronda]
                        ? [...acc[ronda], val]
                        : [val];
        return acc;
    }, []); // El segundo argumento de la llamada es un array vacío
            // que será la primera declaración del resultado de reduce.
            // Conviene leer la documentación si no entiendes esto.
```

Con el siguiente conjunto de valores, el resultado quedaría de la siguiente forma.

```javascript
const respuesta2 = [
    { ronda: 0, victorias_1: 3, victorias_2: 2},
    { ronda: 1, victorias_1: 6, victorias_2: 5},
    { ronda: 5, victorias_1: 7, victorias_2: 0},
    { ronda: 3, victorias_1: 5, victorias_2: 7},
    { ronda: 1, victorias_1: 4, victorias_2: 1},
    { ronda: 5, victorias_1: 0, victorias_2: 2}
];
const resultados_f2 = digest(respuesta2);
console.log(resultados_f2);
// [
//     [ [ 3, 2 ] ],
//     [ [ 6, 5 ], [ 4, 1 ] ],
//     <1 empty item>,
//     [ [ 5, 7 ] ],
//     <1 empty item>,
//     [ [ 7, 0 ], [ 0, 2 ] ]
// ]
```

Si te fijas, hay posiciones del *array* que no tienen valor porque no había ningún con la propiedad `ronda` con el valor de esa posición.

Personalmente, ya que esto se puede dar, optaría por sacar como resultado un *object*, quedaría más limpio, pero depende de ti.

```
const digestToObject = arr =>
    arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        // La implementación es idéntica
        // A tratar con un array
    }, {}); // El valor inicial será un object.
```

Con el mismo *set* de datos de antes, este es el resultado,

```javascript
const resultados_f2 = digestToObject(respuesta2);
console.log(resultados_f2);
// {
//     '0': [ [ 3, 2 ] ],
//     '1': [ [ 6, 5 ], [ 4, 1 ] ],
//     '3': [ [ 5, 7 ] ],
//     '5': [ [ 7, 0 ], [ 0, 2 ] ]
// }
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Increíble.. es perfecto, muchas gracias. Me voy a documentar más sobre reduce.